# SQL SUM() function not working properly with multiple tables in query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to pull the sum of hours worked worked and compare it to the sum of hours paid for each individual employee. These are stored in two different tables. When I query the tables separately into 2 different tables they work perfect. When I place them in the same query the results are way off.

Sample Data-PayrollTransactions:
[PayrollTransactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAW9N.png)

[image]

[PayrollTime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKraT.png)

[image]

This is the query that does not work:

```
SELECT Emp_No, Sum(Regular_Hours) AS PaidRegHours, Sum(Overtime_Hours) AS PaidOTHours, Sum(Reg_Hours) AS ClockedRegHours, Sum(OT_Hrs) AS ClockedOTHours
FROM PayrollTransactions, PayrollTime
WHERE Employee_No = Emp_No
GROUP BY Emp_No;
```

The result it pulls for 1 employee is 1000 PaidRegHours. When doing a query just from PayrollTransactions as such:

```
SELECT Employee_No, Sum(Regular_Hours) AS PaidRegHours, Sum(Overtime_Hours) AS PaidOTHours
FROM PayrollTransactions
GROUP BY Employee_No;
```

the result for that same employee is 200 PaidRegHours, which is correct. This same problem exists for all my computed fields. I am unsure how to fix this problem. Thanks for your help!

Desired Results:
[DesiredOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/016bX.png)

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is totally unclear what columns come from which tables, why the `JOIN` is needed, and where the problem might lie.

Comment: I just edited my post to include a screenshot of some of the data and the desired result. Let me know if I need to include anything else! I am new here and am unsure what would be the best to include. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic problem of `JOIN` multiples. By querying these two tables that share a many-to-many relationship on employee, you return multiple pairings (i.e., duplicates, triplets, quadruples) that are then aggregated, turning actual 200 to 1,000 summed hours. Instead, consider joining one-to-one pairs which can be achieved by joining aggregates of both tables.

Below uses subqueries but can also use stored queries. Also, the explicit `JOIN` is used (current ANSI SQL standard) and not implicit join as you currently have with `WHERE`.

```
SELECT p.Employee_No, p.PaidRegHours, p.PaidOTHours, t.ClockedRegHours, t.ClockedOTHours
FROM
   (SELECT Employee_No, 
           Sum(Regular_Hours) AS PaidRegHours, 
           Sum(Overtime_Hours) AS PaidOTHours
    FROM PayrollTransactions
    GROUP BY Employee_No) p
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT Emp_No, 
           Sum(Reg_Hours) AS ClockedRegHours, 
           Sum(OT_Hrs) AS ClockedOTHours
    FROM PayrollTime
    GROUP BY Emp_No) t
  ON p.Employee_No = t.Emp_No
```

Alternatively, with stored queries which sometimes can be more efficient with Access' engine:

```
SELECT p.Employee_No, p.PaidRegHours, p.PaidOTHours, t.ClockedRegHours, t.ClockedOTHours
FROM qryPayrollTransactionsAgg p
INNER JOIN qryPayrollTimeAgg t
  ON p.Employee_No = t.Emp_No
```